# Basis for eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is the 1-eigenspace and 2-eigenspace just the eigenspaces that correspond to eigen values 1 and 2 respectively?
I need to find the bases for the 1-eigenspace and 2-eigenspace of a matrix. So to do this, would I just row reduce the matrix to find the eigen value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes 1 and 2 are eigenvalues of the given matrix, denote it by $A$. Then *all* the solutions of the  homogeneous system $(A-I)x=0$ make the 1-eigenspace; similarly for the 2-eigenspace you collect all the solutions of $(A-2I)x=0$.

Added in EDIT: To get the basis for the eigenspace you do the same thing when you write all solutions of a linear system with infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Bye_world You are right. I'll edit it.